# interagir com TD com linha canvas sobre a TABLE

Tags: html, css, canvas

Tenho uma tabela comum informado determinado raio de coordenadas geometricas, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe uma função javascript que calcula a distancia do ponto 'char (0,0)' até qualquer ponto marcado, e desenha esta linha em canvas, o problema é, quando esta linha desenhada, pra ela ser exibida, preciso trazer o elemento 'canvas' pra cima do elemento 'table', eu preciso de alguma forma, desenhar a linha sobre o elemento table, mantendo table sobre o canvas, pois preciso interagir com os 'td' (coordenadas) dessa table.

Para a tabela:

```
<table>
...coisas
</table>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Pra colocar um elemento sobre o outro eu uso:

```
position: absolute; top: 0px;
```

E após desenhar a linha:

```
 z-index: 0;
```

Existe como fazer isso com css apenas?

Comment: Vc quer desenhar a linha em um canvas por cima da tabela, mesmo assim vc quer que o usuário possa clicar na tabela que está abaixo do canvas é isso?

Comment: @hugocsl bem isso mesmo

Comment: Coloca z-index:-1 no canvas, assim ele fica por baixo da tabela